# Porque obtengo Invalid login attempt en mi consulta soap a netsuite?

Tags: post, soap, postman

Estoy tratando de hacer una peticion simple a netSuite desde postman. Estoy usando un pre request script para obtener signature en HMAC-SHA256.
Este es el cuerpo de mi solicitud los campos del tokenPassport se rellenan en el script que muestro despues.

```
    <soap-env:Envelope 
    xmlns:soap-env="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"
    xmlns:xsd='http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema'
    xmlns:xsi='http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance'
    xmlns:soapenv='http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/'
    xmlns:platformCore='urn:core_2021_1.platform.webservices.netsuite.com'
    xmlns:platformMsgs='urn:messages_2021_1.platform.webservices.netsuite.com'>
   <soap-env:Header>
    <tokenPassport>
      <account>{{ACCOUNT}}</account>
      <consumerKey>{{CONSUMER_KEY}}</consumerKey>
      <token>{{TOKEN_ID}}</token>
      <nonce>{{nonce}}</nonce>
      <timestamp>{{timestamp}}</timestamp>
      <signature algorithm="HMAC-SHA256">{{signature}}</signature>
    </tokenPassport>
  </soap-env:Header>
  <soap-env:Body>
    <get xsi:type='platformMsgs:GetRequest'>
        <baseRef xsi:type='platformCore:RecordRef' internalId='13490' type='customer'/>
    </get>
  </soap-env:Body>
</soap-env:Envelope>
```

Y este mi script que genera la signature, timestamp y nonce y los pone en el environment junto con el resto de datos para la autenticación.

```
let account = 'XXXX';
let consumerKey = 'XXXX';
let consumerSecret = 'XXXX';
let tokenId = 'XXXX';
let tokenSecret = 'XXXX';

    
let timestamp = new Date().getTime().toString().substring(0, 10);
let nonce = CryptoJS.lib.WordArray.random(10).toString();
let baseString = `${account}&${consumerKey}&${tokenId}&${nonce}&${timestamp}`;
let key = `${consumerSecret}&${tokenSecret}`;
let signature = CryptoJS.HmacSHA256(baseString, key).toString(CryptoJS.enc.Base64);

console.log({account,consumerKey,consumerSecret,tokenId, tokenSecret, signature, nonce, timestamp})
pm.environment.set("ACCOUNT", account);
pm.environment.set("CONSUMER_KEY", consumerKey);
pm.environment.set("CONSUMER_SECRET", consumerSecret);
pm.environment.set("TOKEN_ID", consumerSecret);
pm.environment.set("signature", signature);
pm.environment.set("nonce", nonce);
pm.environment.set("timestamp", timestamp);
```

Estos son mis headers la Authorization la tengo configurada en No Auth y la peticion es tipo POST
[image: postman headers]